# Opera snap browser on Ubuntu 20.04 - Slow to load with errors

Tags: snap, opera

I am trying to use Opera snap on Ubunt20.04.  This has been loaded form the Ubuntu Software App (snap-store)

Opera is very slow to load.
If is run opera from the terminal the following series of errors are displayed during the long loading process:

```
$ opera

(opera:282340): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:06:10.643: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1428:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(opera:282340): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:06:10.649: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3318:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(opera:282340): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:06:10.650: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3780:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
[282340:282340:0506/110629.601695:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(259)] Invalid url pattern: chrome://startpage/
[282340:282340:0506/110629.601878:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(259)] Invalid url pattern: chrome://startpage/
[282340:282340:0506/110629.601939:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(259)] Invalid url pattern: chrome://startpage/
[282340:282340:0506/110629.664197:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(975)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=512
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[282508:282508:0506/110637.364062:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282508:282508:0506/110637.364421:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282508:282508:0506/110637.364500:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[282508:282508:0506/110637.603991:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282508:282508:0506/110637.604170:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282508:282508:0506/110637.604246:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[282508:282508:0506/110637.604318:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(20)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[282508:282508:0506/110637.862536:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[282696:282696:0506/110642.897623:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282696:282696:0506/110642.897863:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282696:282696:0506/110642.897940:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[282696:282696:0506/110642.899024:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282696:282696:0506/110642.900229:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282696:282696:0506/110642.911862:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[282696:282696:0506/110642.911979:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(20)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[282696:282696:0506/110642.915592:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[282340:282340:0506/110646.476259:ERROR:named_platform_channel_posix.cc(146)] connect /home/tony/snap/opera/175/.config/opera/oauc_pipe_r: Connection refused (111)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[282837:282837:0506/110646.578900:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282837:282837:0506/110646.579131:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282837:282837:0506/110646.579200:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[282837:282837:0506/110646.580011:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282837:282837:0506/110646.580093:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[282837:282837:0506/110646.580157:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[282837:282837:0506/110646.580216:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(20)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[282837:282837:0506/110646.587198:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[283084:283084:0506/110647.570670:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[283084:283084:0506/110647.570979:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[283084:283084:0506/110647.571080:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[283084:283084:0506/110647.571936:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[283084:283084:0506/110647.572024:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[283084:283084:0506/110647.572089:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[283084:283084:0506/110647.572152:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(20)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[283084:283084:0506/110647.576046:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[282340:282340:0506/110702.789255:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(975)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=512
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
[283192:283192:0506/110703.865182:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[283192:283192:0506/110707.504485:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[282671:8:0506/110708.223071:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[282655:7:0506/110708.225664:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[282644:8:0506/110708.226218:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[282659:8:0506/110708.280366:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[282340:282340:0506/110719.419117:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source: chrome://startpage/ (0)
```

Comment: `Opera is very slow to load` -- This is a known issue with snaps. Use the .deb package instead. https://www.opera.com/computer/thanks?partner=www&par=id=57351%26location=415&gaprod=opera It would automatically add an apt repository which so that Opera will be updated when you update the computer.

Answer (score 1):

**Dont Use Snap!**
Almost all snaps are slow when loading. I dont know if there is an opera .deb package or `apt-get install opera` exists since i dont use this browser, but i try to avoid snap as much as i can and you should too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Opera.deb package has a well documented problem in playing videos caused by a deficiency in the file libffmpeg.so. The snap does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also find that the opera snap loads very slowly.
This issue is due to the opera snap (mid 2022).
Its not because it is a snap.
Many snaps load slowly the first time, and subsequently load quite quickly. Its especially noticeable with large apps, such as browsers.
In the case of opera snap, the optimizing on the first run, seems to not happen.
Im using snaps for 3 browsers, and only the opera snap has this issue. I like the benefits of snap sandboxing - the internet has extremely grubby hands - i want it to put on rubber gloves to visit me. For me, this benefit makes the repeating slow loading not much of an issue.
i hope the opera team fixes this, as it can be over 10s to get to a usable state. I also find that the window always loads with the default size, not full screen - window load params are not saved. Other things seem to work normally, once loaded.